# Sklearn.neighbors Classifier - Order of results in case of a tie

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am having an ordering problem with the Sklearn.neighbors classifier. Namely, what I want is in case of a tie the classifier to predict the first result appearing on the dataframe.

The documentation of Sklearn.neighbors says:

> ''Warning Regarding the Nearest Neighbors algorithms, if two
>   neighbors, neighbor k+1 and k, have identical distances but different
>   labels, the results will depend on the ordering of the training
>   data.''

However I found out that this is true only in case I use as an algorithm ''brute force'' i.e:

```
clf = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='brute').fit(X)
```

My problem is that even by using brute as an algorithm, the order gets lost after a specific number of predicting neighbors. Namely:

```
clf.kneighbors(np.array(y), n_neighbors=1) -> Predicts 0 row which is correct in terms of ordering
clf.kneighbors(np.array(y), n_neighbors=2) -> Predicts 0 and 101 rows which are correct in terms of ordering
clf.kneighbors(np.array(y), n_neighbors=3) -> Predicts 0, 101 and 115 rows which are correct in terms of ordering
```

But then when I use n_neighbors=4 I get:

```
clf.kneighbors(np.array(y), n_neighbors=4) -> Predicts 4416, 223, 7626 and 2047 rows which are not correct in terms of ordering
```

And it keeps going like this for any number>3. The order is completely lost.

Anyone that has dealt with this problem before?

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. Are you sure that the distances are the same for 4416, 223, 7627 in the n_neighbors=4 case

Comment: amanbirs yes. This specific problem that I am dealing with, has a big number of ties and all of them in 0 distance. All the results I mentioned have 0 distance from target y.

Comment: Very strange, could you share a bit of the data so we can re-create the problem?